# cx_freeze yields "NameError: name 'build_exe_options' is not defined" on build attempt

Tags: python-3.x, build, cx-freeze, nameerror

I am running Python 3.3 and cx_freeze 3.3 x86 on Win XP x86.

I have a setup file and my application file in the same directory, the setup file contains the following:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(  name = "Duplicate Finder x86",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Duplicate Finder x86",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("Comparator Source.py", base=base)])
```

I attempt my build using this command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Construction Yard>C:\Python33\Python setup.py build
```

And I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    options = <"build_exe": build_exe_options>,
NameError: name 'build_exe_options' is not defined
```

I am not experienced with using cx_freeze, but I feel that I have most of the pieces in place here.
Any help as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. 
I was using a modified version of the example setup script given on the documentation page.
I needed to remove unnecessary portions, modifying it to the following:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(  name = "Duplicate Finder x86",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Duplicate Finder x86",
    executables = [Executable("Comparator Source.py")])
```